# stop the web page from loading programmatically

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I want to create an extension to firefox using addon builder that
stops users from visiting a malicious website; When I see a URL that is
suspicious, I stop the page from loading and ask the user if he really
wants to visit the site. How could I implement that? I am expecting the functionality programmatically, so that I can make an extension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an event called [beforescriptexecute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla_event_reference/beforescriptexecute) supported my mozilla ..... Have a look , I think it will work the job for you. But what you desire can be done something like this:

```
var r=confirm("Are you sure you want to visit this site ?"); 
if (r==false) { window.stop(); }
```

Answer (score 9):

```
if(site.is_malicious)
   window.stop();
```

Comment: Thanks, it is working fine. and it is stopping the remaining scripts to be loaded in the web page after this statement.but already loaded scripts displaying the webpage. Can we reset whole web page, means the user shouldn't see web page,if he finds suspiciousness while loading web page.

Answer (score 3):

You are creating a FF extension right? Why not use greasemonkey or so? You can execute a script BEFORE the page loads(on greasemonkey). when that script is called, you can potentially stop the pageload and throw an error message.

Comment: According to the tags he is using the Add-on SDK - meaning that he can use the `page-mod` module to do anything a GreaseMonkey script can do just as easily.